# large and small quantities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I'm stuck on a few problems.

> 1) If an ant travels $50$ cm per second and decides to travel 2760 miles, how many days would it take to arrive to their destination?

First, I converted miles to centimeters. $1$ mi $=160934$ cm, so $2760$ mi is $4.4417784 \times 10^8$. With $t$ representing our time in seconds, I have $$(4.4417784 \times 10^8)=50t \\ t= 8.883568 \times 10^7 \ \text{seconds}$$

Converting this to days, $$\cfrac{(8.883568 \times 10^7)}{60 \times 60 \times 24} \\ \approx 10.28 \text{ days}$$

But I'm marked wrong here, so I must have made a mistake. The answer doesn't even look remotely correct because it seems too low.

> 2) The Sahara Desert has an area of approximately $9,400,400$ km$^2$. While estimates of its average depth vary, they center around $150$ m. One cm$^3$ holds approximately $8,000$ grains of sand.
>
> a) Approximately how many grains of sand are in the Sahara Desert?
>
> b) Express your answer to part a) in millions of grains of sand.
>
> c) What fraction of the Sahara is made by $1$ grain of sand (select units for your solution as well)?
>
> d) A small dump truck can carry approximately $20.5$ m$^3$ of sand. Suppose a long line of dump trucks were to dump a load of sand every $30$ seconds. How many years would it take to re-create the Sahara Desert?

a) Here I converted 150 m to km, which got me 0.15 km for the deserts depth. Then I figured I needed to know how many times 0.15 goes into the area. This is $62,669,333.33$ or ${6.266933333 \times 10^7}$. At this point I'm not sure how to account for the fact that 1/100,000 km holds 8,000 grains of sand.

b) I can't attempt this problem without knowing the answer to a)

c) $150$ m to km $= 0.15$ km. The area * 0.15 should get me the total amount of sand, so $\cfrac{1}{6.266933333 \times 10^7}$ should be our answer. I was marked correct, at least.

d) I can't answer this without knowing a), either. I think I have an idea how to solve it if I knew the first answer. If V was the amount of sand in total and x was our time in seconds, then I just take the rate per second instead of per 30 seconds and say $41x/60 = V$, then after solving for x I express it in years, right?

Can I get some help?

Comment: 1) Your calculations are off by a factor of $10$. 2) Are you to assume that the Sahara desert is shaped like a cuboid? That is, the depth of the desert is _same_ at every point?

Comment: I honestly have no clue. I mostly did some guesswork here because I've never had to to problems like these. Usually I'm given a little more information.

Comment: You dropped a factor $10$ inc converting to days in the first

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1) Check your calculations

2) I assume that the desert is shaped like a cuboid. The area is $9{,}400{,}400\mathrm{km^2} = 9.4004\times10^{16}\mathrm{cm^2}$. The depth is $150\mathrm m = 15{,}000\mathrm{cm}$. The volume of the cuboid is then $1.41006\times10^{21}\mathrm{cm^3}$. If $1\mathrm{cm^3}$ contains $8{,}000$ grains of sand, then how many does the total volume of the desert contain?